# New shadow technique

Tags: 3d

Does somebody know something about new technique for making shadows called "Shadows dropper" ?
I hear about it in school, but I can't find anything about it. Mayby it has another name ?

Comment: You might have better  luck with this question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/